# Issue with Kafka Connect (Docker) cancelled in-flight API request

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using the following docker compose snippet:

```
version: '3'
services:
  kafka-connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server-connect:latest
    restart: always
    hostname: kafka-connect
    container_name: kafka-connect
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "xxx:123"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "localhost"
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: "xxxx"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: "my-connect-configs"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: "my-connect-offsets"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: "my-connect-status"
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/Users/c/Kafka/confluent-7.3.0/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc/lib,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components,"
      CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: "SASL_SSL"
      CONNECT_SASL_MECHANISM: "PLAIN"
      CONNECT_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='xxxxxxxx' password='xxxxxxxxxxx';"
ports:
      - "8083:8083"
```

The container starts up fine. and I can add a JDBC source connection via the REST API

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8083/connectors' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "name": "JdbcSourceConnectorConnector_0",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://xxxxx:xxx",
    "connection.user": "dbkafka",
    "connection.password": "xxxxx",
    "table.whitelist": "table",
    "mode": "bulk",
    "topic.prefix": "Test"
  }
}'
```

This connection also seems to work fine. However the logs are always showing the following mistake:

```
INFO [Producer clientId=connector-producer-JdbcSourceConnectorConnector_0] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
INFO [Producer clientId=connector-producer-JdbcSourceConnectorConnector_0] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 461 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 24ms, elapsed time since send: 24ms, request timeout: 30000ms) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

I cannot really find what is wrong with my connector, especially as it is not giving me a decent error message.

Answer (score 0):

1. The bootstrap server address you've set needs to match Kafka cluster's own `advertised.listeners` value.

   https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

   And for any external Kafka server, the firewall should also allow connections
2. verify your SASL user/pass is correct. I see you have no `CONNECT_PRODUCER_` settings. Ref. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/authentication_sasl_plain.html#crep-full

> not giving me a decent error message

You can modify log4j values

```
CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka=DEBUG,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR"
```

But `Node -1 disconnected` is exactly the error you would expect on an invalid network connection.